# Build a hyperbola using cubic or quadratic Bézier curves

Tags: bezier-curve

I have a hyperbola defined with an equation `y = A/x`.

How to build approximation of this hyperbola in a given rectangular area `0 < x <= x1, 0 < y <= y1` using cubic or quadratic Bézier curves, so that the difference between approximation and hyperbola would not exceed some delta?

I need to write a program that has `A`, `x1`, `y1`, `delta` as the input, and it should output SVG path to draw the given hyperbola.

Comment: There's really no such thing as "the closest" approximation. If you allow the number of control points to go to infinity, the Bézier curve approximation will eventually converge to the hyperbola.

Comment: By "the closest" approximation I mean to use the minimum number of control points so that difference between approximation and hyperbola would not exceed some delta. (0.01 mm for example)